# How would I say "It's nice, right?" In Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I posted about loving airports and when someone agreed with me I wanted to respond with "いいでしょ？" but I'm not sure it's the right response.

Comment: To judge the appropriateness/naturalness of "いいでしょ？" in said situation, I think we'd be in better position if we knew exact words exchanged (or at least those said by your interlocutor) prior to it.

Answer (score 4):

I would say...

> いいですよねー！
>   いいよねー！ ← casual

Comment: （なんで「ね」じゃなくて「よね」？って聞かれると説明できませんけど・・・）

Comment: In response to your comment, 「よ」 was taught to me as a marker for emphasis/declaration - often added to something which the speaker feels is exciting and/or certain. So, maybe it adds a little more of an excited tone? Also, I remember it being said that men may use it to avoid "sounding like a girl" when「ね」 would otherwise appear alone. It's been a while since I've studied, though. Does that sound right?

Comment: @BDawg That explanation is wrong. よ doesn't add a more excited tone (nor the gender factor). It implies possible disagreement between the listener about the information.

Comment: @user4092 Thanks for the help. I went back and tried to re-learn よ. I'm seeing the words "assert" and "assumption" show up quite often. Based on what I read and the context here, よね doesn't imply disagreement like よ could. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, よね is seeking agreement under some uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

That's just right. If you want to be a bit more polite, you could instead say

> いいですね？
>
> 素敵ですね？ It's beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: Corresponding to "It's beautiful, isn't it?" we say "素敵**でしょう！**"  We neither say "素敵**ですね？**", "素敵**ですね！**" nor "素敵でしょう **？** "  For "いいですね？", we say "いいでしょう！"

Comment: I guess it's hard to distinguish a ? from a ! just from common intonation. Do you mean that a downtone on the last syllable on でしょう is a ! and not a ? ? That's how it always sounds to me. And I have, from anecdotal experience, heard 素敵でしょう with a downtone on multiple occasions.

Comment: For "素敵でしょう！ *It's beautiful, isn't it?*", we say it with an uptone and with a little stressed tone at でしょう.  If you say 素敵でしょう in a common intonation, it implies that "I don't care but it may be beautiful".  If you want to say "It's beautiful", we say 素敵だ or 素敵です. If you want to say "Is it beautiful?", we say 素敵？ or 素敵ですか？ with a uptone.

Answer (score 0):

Kansai-ben answer:

> （めっちゃ）え〜やろッ！

Answer (score 0):

I would say いいですねー。(iidesune) which translates to 'It's good, right?' Just saying, いいです！(iidesu) Would translate to 'That's good' as a statement, but by adding ね (ne) this creates the '-right?' part of, eliciting or encouraging a response of agreement from the listener.

Comment: In this case, いいですね doesn't mean "it's good, right?". You can't seek agreement with ね only, unless the listener exactly perceives source of the goodness.

Answer (score 0):

depends on how u want it to sound いいじゃないか